# PostgreSQL (copy or replication of missing data) - read only permission on remote master PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

First of all i do not know if is possible what i want to achive, will describe below:

1. I have access of a remote PostgreSQL that holds the data i need (let's say **Remote PostgreSQL 1**)

   - have just credentials to read from database
2. What i want to achive is to create a localt PostgreSQL on my machine (let's say **Local PostgreSQL 2**)
3. Want to copy and check for missing data from **Remote PostgreSQL 1 to Local PostgreSQL 2** in real time or at list to copy at the end of the day data

The scenario will work perfect with replication but the issue is that ***Remote PostgreSQL 1 is not owned by me*** and can not be used as real time DB, because of this trying to find a solution to get all the data from **Remote PostgreSQL 1 to Local PostgreSQL 2**.

**Could be the following scenarios:**

- first time setup to downlaod all the database from Remote PostgreSQL 1 to Local PostgreSQL 2
- after first time setup to check what data came new inside and add them in Local PostgreSQL 2

Would be great if this could be done on OS level on UBUNTU. My application is written in python 3 i could do scripts to do all this job but i speak of 100 millions of raws per table huge amount of data. Think will be problems to get everything from database and start to check everything what is missing and not.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the owner of Remote Database 1 won't cooperate with you other than to give you read only access to the tables, then you don't have any efficient options.  If the remote owner does or can be convinced to keep insertion/modification timestamp columns in all the tables (although then deletions would be a problem), or an in-database "audit" log for all the tables, you could use those.  I think you have an organizational/political problem rather a programming problem.

Comment: thanks, i also came out with exact opinion, writing down a python script to take care for replication.